Formatting x axis as Date and footnote in highcharter
I have the following code snippet.
library(highcharter)

Year <- 2001:2020
X <- rnorm(20)
Y <- rnorm(20)

dataf <- data.frame(Year, X, Y)

highcharter::highchart() |> 
  hc_add_series(name = "Hessen", 
                data = dataf$X, 
                color = "green",
                type = "column") |> 
  hc_add_series(name = "Deutschland", 
                data = dataf$Y, 
                color = "blue",
                type = "column") |>
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", 
           labels = list(format = "%Y"))  |> 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "X and Y", 
                        color = "black"))

I have two questions:

The dates are not showing correctly. How to make it work?
How to add footnote at the bottom of the plot?


1: You are not mapping Year to the x axis, your data arguments to hc_add_series are just vectors. 2: Does hc_caption do the trick?

Try this:
highcharter::highchart() |> 
  hc_add_series(name = "Hessen", 
                data = dataf$X, 
                color = "green",
                type = "column") |> 
  
  hc_add_series(name = "Deutschland", 
                data = dataf$Y, 
                color = "blue",
                type = "column") |>
  
  hc_xAxis(categories = dataf$Year)  |> # Here!
  
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "X and Y", 
                        color = "black"))

Output:

